# Validation data on instance when call __init__

Tags: python, validation, oop

This is the evaluation of the evaluation is the evaluation of the main is the date will be used in the same.

I can't call her inside the builder.

How valid are those data or I call a function earlier than the methods I call them are executed.

```
class Date():

    def __init__(self, day = 1, month = 1, year = 1980):
        self.__day = day
        self.__month = month
        self.__year = year

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.getDay()}/{self.getMonth()}/{self.getYear()}'

    def _valida(self, day = 0, month = 0, year = 0):
        if day < 1 or day > 31:
            return False
        elif month < 1 or month > 12:
            return False
        elif year < 1: 
            return False
        return True

    def ePrevious(self, dateComp):
        if dateComp.getYear() > self.getYear():
            return False
        elif dateComp.getYear() == self.getYear() and dateComp.getMonth() > self.getMonth():
            return False
        elif dateComp.getYear() == self.getYear() and dateComp.getMonth() == self.getMonth() and dateComp.getDay() >= self.getDay():
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def eLater(self, dateComp):
        if dateComp.getYear() < self.getYear():
            return False
        elif dateComp.getYear() == self.getYear() and dateComp.getMonth() < self.getMonth():
            return False
        elif dateComp.getYear() == self.getYear() and dateComp.getMonth() == self.getMonth() and dateComp.getDay() <= self.getDay():
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def eSimultaneous(self, dateComp):
        if dateComp.getYear() != self.getYear():
            return False
        elif dateComp.getYear() == self.getYear() and dateComp.getMonth() != self.getMonth():
            return False
        elif dateComp.getYear() == self.getYear() and dateComp.getMonth() == self.getMonth() and dateComp.getDay() != self.getDay():
            return False
        else:
            return True    

    def setData(self, day, month, year):
        if self._valida(day, month, year):
            self.setDay(day)
            self.setMonth(month)
            self.setYear(year)
        else:
            self.setDay(1)
            self.setMonth(1)
            self.setYear(1980)

    def getDay(self):
        return self.__day

    def setDay(self, day):
        self.__day = day

    def getMonth(self):
        return self.__month

    def setMonth(self, month):
        self.__month = month

    def getYear(self):
        return self.__year

    def setYear(self, year):
        self.__year = year
```

In this case, I can put any value on `Date()` including strings.

I can't allow this.

Comment: did you consider using [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use properties in place of the trivial getter/setter methods you currently have.

```
class Date():

    def __init__(self, day=1, month=1, year=1980):
        # Order important!
        # You might want to extend the validation of the day
        # to take into account the month and year, so you need
        # to ensure that self.__year and self.__month are set
        # at that time.
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day

    @property
    def day(self):
        return self.__day

    @property
    def month(self):
        return self.__month

    @property
    def year(self):
        return self.__year

    @day.setter
    def day(self, d):
        if d < 1 or d > 31:
            raise ValueError("Day out of range")
        # Simple example extension: month-aware day ranges
        # if self.__month == 2 and day > 28:
        #  raise ValueError("February has only 28 days")
        self.__day = d

    @month.setter
    def month(self, m):
        if m < 1 or m > 12:
            raise ValueError("Month out of range")
        self.__month = m

    @year.setter
    def year(self, y):
        if y < 1:
            raise ValueError("Year out of range")
        self.__year = y

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.day}/{self.month}/{self.year}'

    def ePrevious(self, dateComp):
        return (dateComp.year <= self.year
                and dateComp.month <= self.month
                and dateComp.day < self.day)

    def eLater(self, dateComp):
        return (dateComp.year >= self.year
                and dateComp.month >= self.month
                and dateComp.day > self.day)

    def eSimultaneous(self, dateComp):
        return (dateComp.year == self.year
                and dateComp.month == self.month
                and dateComp.day == self.day)

    def setData(self, day, month, year):
        try:
            self.day = day
            self.month = month
            self.year = year
        except ValueError:
            self.day = 1
            self.month = 1
            self.year = 1980
```

Comment: In this case, using @property, is the attribute not understood as a method?

Can I use a simple assignment that he will call the setter?

And with that, at the moment of assignment he will look for the setter decorator, will he validate or not?

Comment: `property` is a type which implements `__get__` and `__set__` according to the descriptor protocol, and those methods use your decorated functions when you access the `day`, `month`, and `year` attributes via an instance of your class. See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

While not very pythonic, you can check the type of a variable.

```
    def __init__(self, day = 1, month = 1, year = 1980):
        if not isinstance(day, int):
            raise TypeError("PROVIDE AN ERROR MESSAGE")
        if not isinstance(month, int):
            raise TypeError("PROVIDE AN ERROR MESSAGE")
        if not isinstance(year, int):
            raise TypeError("PROVIDE AN ERROR MESSAGE")
        self.__day = day
        self.__month = month
        self.__year = year
```